# images in same level php

Tags: html, css, image

I was wondering how can I place images in PHP one next to another. For example:

image  image  image  image.

Right now,using this code:

```
print "</h2><br><a href='form.php'><img src=***.jpg width=100 height=100  /><br>
House Specifications </a><br><div>";
echo "<br>";
print "</h2><br><a href='devices.php'><img src=***.jpg width=100 height=100  /><br>Devices  </a><br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "</h2><br><a href='new_info.php'><img src=***.jpg width=100 height=100  /><br>
Change Contact Info</a><br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "</h2><br><a href='events.php'><img src=***.jpgwidth=100 height=100  /><br>
Events</a><br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
print "<br></h2><br><div align= 'center'><a href='logout.php'><img src=***.jpg width=100 height=100  /><br>Logout</a><br>";
```

;the result is like this:

image

image

image

image.

Please help.

Comment: Consider asking in an HTML/CSS related post. This has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: uh, if you want them next to each other, why are you spitting out `<br>`, `<h2>`, and `<div>`? You need to learn basic HTML...

Comment: This is a CSS question. Fix your tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete all the HTML tags, its completely broken and you have tags that are explicitly telling the browser to draw newlines. Also, this is a CSS / HTML question, not PHP...

Change to something like this:

```
//container div
echo "<div>";
//one image per line
echo "<a href='form.php'><img src='img1.jpg' width='100' height='100' /></a>";
echo "<a href='form.php'><img src='img2.jpg' width='100' height='100'  /></a>";
echo "<a href='form.php'><img src='img3.jpg' width='100' height='100'  /></a>";
echo "<a href='form.php'><img src='img4.jpg' width='100' height='100' /></a>";
echo "</div>";
```

by the way, you dont need php to do any of this.